# MySQL insert date if no field exists

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to get insert date/time for rows if there was no insert_date field. I have a database which I configured to store insert_date but can I populate the field before that change ( month ago ). Is that even possible?

Pull that insert date/time from log or something else?

Comment: It is called update `UPDATE your_table SET insert_date = NOW() WHERE insert_date IS NULL` You can set arbitrary date.

Comment: But will now put current date or date/time whent that row was inserted? I need to get date/time when that row was inserted even if that field wasn't there before.

Comment: And from where do you want that date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. If that date wasn't stored before, it's impossible to find out when a row was inserted. The best you can do is just pick a date, or maybe make a rough estimate if you have information to base that on (for instance, the create date of a customer might be related to the date of their first invoice)..

By the way, you can add timestamp columns and specify the clause `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to set a timestamp as soon as you insert the row. That way, you don't need a trigger to update the row.

You can even add a clause `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` so the column (or a different column) is updated automatically too.

See [Timestamp initialization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for more information about this subject.

This doesn't change the fact, though, that you cannot get those values for rows that already exist.